# Where are my screenshots saved?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I'm trying to find where my prints screens are going in South Park Stick of Truth.

So far I've searched in My Pictures, My Documents and the location of the game, but I've had no luck so far. :(

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Usually, Steam games will save screenshots... wherever steam saves screenshots... if you press the "F12" key (not the PrtScr key), I believe. I'm not entirely certain. Steam should pop up with your screenshots that session if you use that.

Comment: @Ender Not a duplicate. That's for a different game, and one that doesn't use Steam at all.

Comment: @Ender you are able to withdraw your close vote.

Comment: @MBraedley thanks I didn't know that

Comment: Does the game have built-in screenshot functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have actually taken any screenshots (that is, by default, using the <kbd>F12</kbd> key), your screenshots should be stored in `{steam root}\userdata\{user id}\760\remote\213670\screenshots`

`{steam root}` is, by default, `C:\Program Data (x86)`.

`{user id}` is most likely the only directory on that level anyway.

---

That said, after a play session during which you took a screenshot, Steam will (by default) prompt you with a Screenshot Manager window, which should give you access to cloud upload and, more importantly, a button to open the actual directory.

You can also change these settings via *Steam → Settings → In-Game*, which offers more tailored preferences:

[image: Steam Settings Dialog]

Comment: Arghh screen shot is F12 you say....

Comment: @JamieHutber yeah the printscreen button on your keyboard saves to the clipboard, you need to paste it somewhere (paint or something like that) before they are saved permanently

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to view your screenshots is to go to `view --> screenshots` in Steam, then select the game.

Once there, you can click *"show on disk"* if you need access to the actual image file.