# Where is Stellaris' screenshots location?

Tags: stellaris

I've got the Steam edition of *Stellaris*. Pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> notifies "Screenshot Taken", but I can't find it.

Does anyone know where Stellaris' screenshots are located?

Comment: Can you link this "no Steam edition"? As far as I can tell, the Steam release was the only release.

Comment: Related: [Where did my (Steam) screenshots go?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30051/3062) and [Where are my screenshots saved?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159199/3062) (for another Steam game)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using windows, the screenshots taken with F11 are stored in:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Paradox Interactive\Stellaris\screenshots

Where USERNAME is your Windows username.

Screenshots taken with the Steam overlay (default F12) are stored with the rest of your Steam screenshots and can be managed with Steam.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone playing on Linux, look in:

```
~/.local/share/Paradox Interactive/Stellaris/screenshots
```